# prevent multiple database fetches when paginating results using flask-paginate

Tags: python, flask, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, flask-wtforms

I have a flask app that includes a form. Based on the form data, I am making a call to my database to get data. There may be a lot of results, so I am using flask-paginate make sure there isn't too much scrolling. The problem that I'm running into is that every time I move to a next page, I'm making a new connection to the database and running the query again. I am using a NoSQL database (DynamoDB) and not sql, so I am unable to use the sqlalchemy paginate functionality.

(edit: I was reminded in the comments that dynamo pagination is different from sql pagination, and to clarify, I am aware of the difference and I am not trying to use that)

My question: what is the best way to prevent fetching data the data from the database every time the user goes from one page to the next? How can I persist the results when the page is reloaded?

Here's a code snippet

```
@views.route('/index', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    page, per_page, offset = get_page_args(page_parameter='page',
                                           per_page_parameter='per_page')
    db = DynamoDb() # constructor makes a connection to the database, which is happening every time the user goes to the next page
    my_form = MyForm() # MyForm is a child of FlaskForm
    if my_form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for("views.index", arg_to_pass=my_form.field.data))
    elif request.method == "GET" and request.args.get("arg_to_pass") is not None:
        # db.get_data() makes a request to dynamodb and then formats the result in a dictionary. It's possible that a large number of results will be returned
        # this transaction on dynamodb is also happening every time the user goes to the next page
        # How can I just fetch the data once and persist it when the user goes to the next page?
        large_dict = db.getdata(arg_to_pass) 
        pagination_users = list(large_dict.keys())[offset: offset + per_page]
        pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, total=total, css_framework="bootstrap4")
        return render_template('index.html', my_form=my_form,
                                             large_dict=large_dict
                                             pagination_users=pagination_users
                                             page=page,
                                             per_page=per_page,
                                             pagination=pagination)
    return render_template("index.html", my_form=my_form)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that pagination in DynamoDB does not work the same as SQL databases.  There is no page/per_page options when querying DDB.  You may already know this, but it was not apparent from your question :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm aware. I'm not using dynamo pagination, it's just the flask pagination implementation for displaying the data